# ViewControllers with segmented control performance issue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a list of items in a UITableView, when an item is selected I open a ViewController with a segmented control that is supposed to switch between three different ViewControllers.

I am using a ContainerView to view the ViewControllers along with an array of the three ViewControllers.

The problem is that all three ViewControllers need to be initialized and added to the array when the item is selected from the table. since some of these ViewControllers need to fetch some data from core data, the delay is noticeable when the user selects an item from the table.

Is there a better way to do this segmented control implementation that can improve performance.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing your code. It'd be helpful to know what kind of data you are trying to retrieve so I could determine if using GCD would be helpful or detrimental to your cause.

Comment: In one ViewController I am loading to be plotted in a graph in another I am loading data to be presented in a table. What is GCD? Is there a way that we can load stuff in the background?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading all three view controllers into an array why don't you load them as needed. For example when the SegmentedControl is selected it loads the corresponding ViewController.

Comment: I tried it and it did improve a lot. Gave you one vote up for this. Thanks. But the delay is still noticeable even with one ViewController.

Comment: Okay you are almost there. After you load the VC you should load the data in a background thread. You must be loading both on the main thread. That's why you are noticing a lag. The main thread is being blocked somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are loading a View Controller which is then loading three more view controllers pretty much all at the same time.  It would be better if you loaded the first view controller that holds the segmented control and display it.  The View Controller will call viewDidLoad where you can then load the first View Controller to be displayed.  When the user taps on the segmented control,  load the corresponding view controller at that point, thus only loading extra view controllers as needed.